# jQuery dynamic checkbox event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When appending HTML from a JSON reply, the event handlers appear to lose their event bindings. In using the `.live()` function the handler now appears to work.

```
$.each(result[0], function(i,wellList) {
    $jsonResult = wellList["@name"];
    $uid = wellList["@uid"];
    $dynamicCheckBoxDiv += '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" value="'+ $uid
        + '" class="wellCheck" id="checkbox-'+i+'" />' +
        '<label for="checkbox-'+i+'">' + $jsonResult + '</label>';              
});
$dynamicCheckBoxDiv += '</fieldset></div>';

//Append results to div
$("#dynamicCheck").append($dynamicCheckBoxDiv).page();

$(".wellCheck").live('click', (function() {
```

This event now fires when the click function is run. However, after clicking the checkbox a few times, it randomly associates the checks with the wrong boxes and starts to fire the click event fire on a single click. Has anyone seen this before?

Also: How could I add a method to check all the boxes in a separate button? Since they are being added dynamically it seems to just bypass this function:

```
// When select No wells is clicked this method is run
$('#selectNone').click(function() {
    $('#dynamicCheck .wellCheck').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

It enters the method, but doesnt seem to check any of the boxes. I have jQuery and jQuery mobile added to this page and both methods exist under `document.ready`.

Comment: javascript has ways of defining local variables you know... ***var*** - Please use them instead of polluting the scope.

Comment: The variables are local. They are initialised above the each (still inside the getJSON return function). Is there a reason I should recreate the variable every time I go over the 'each' loop?

Comment: no, sorry I was not aware of that - I assumed you were creating a global variable outside of the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `find(":checkbox")` since the `.wellCheck` element is the checkbox. Just do this:

```
$("#selectNone").click(function(){
    $("#dynamicCheck .wellCheck").prop("checked", true);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/NKbHy/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly! Still trying yo get used to the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of the first bit is that the written-into-HTML listeners only apply on page load.  Any time you're adding raw HTML to the page, you have to set any listeners specifically.  Similarly, just changing the "onclick" attribute does nothing to the listeners.

I suspect your problem with the second bit has something to do with the fact that, at least by my reading, '$(".wellCheck").live(...)' is going to affect every box you've created thus far each time.  You might be better served by something like '$dynamicCheckBoxDiv.live(...)'

I'm not entirely clear on the precise syntax - I worked more with cloned HTML rather than manually constructed, so you may need an intervening step to render it into a DOM object or something (if it's not one already) - but I suspect something like this will help.

Also, you might wish to use '.click(...)', rather than '.live("click", ...)'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegate not live:

```
$("#dynamicCheck").delegate('.wellcheck','click', function(){
//stuff on click
});
```

This would be better bound at that scope than at the body which is what live does.

EDIT: See this for some examples of checkbox management: http://jsfiddle.net/h682v/3/

That uses older attr() and should use prop() instead but the principle remains.

Comment: if I use that function instead of the one I currently have, it doesnt even enter the function on click. Any Ideas?

Comment: Need to change the event to 'change' instead of click (or add it additionally).  You could also add other events like 'focus' etc, including custom events.

Comment: Just to NOT confuse others, this should have the #selectOne not the #dynamicCheck on the selector.  The reason for the original issue as the multiply-applied event handlers.